# How to fix Get-ChildItem -Recurse to handle more than the first level

Tags: powershell, export-to-csv, powershell-3.0, event-log

I try to filter Windows events (id=4633) from eventlogs out of a given filestructure recursivly with `Get-ChildItem`.

The filestructure looks like this:

C:\Temp\raw_data\2018-09\Securitylog\Securitylog_2018-09-14_13-30.evtx

The problem is, that the `Get-ChildItem` only handles the first level. Every level below the first one seems to be ignored.

I tried using the `-Recurse` parameter without success. I don't receive any errors, so I believe the syntax is correct. The codesample is given below.

```
$out = New-Object System.Text.StringBuilder
$out.AppendLine("ServerName,EventID,TimeCreated,UserName,File_or_Folder,AccessMask")
$ns = @{e = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event"}
Get-ChildItem "C:\temp\raw_data" -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
    {
        $evts = Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{Path=$_;id="4663"} -Oldest
        foreach ($evt in $evts) {
            $xml = $evt.ToXml()
            $SubjectUserName = Select-Xml -Xml $xml -Namespace $ns -XPath "//e:Data[@Name='SubjectUserName']/text()" |
                               Select-Object -ExpandProperty Node |
                               Select-Object -ExpandProperty Value
            $ObjectName = Select-Xml -Xml $xml -Namespace $ns -XPath "//e:Data[@Name='ObjectName']/text()" |
                          Select-Object -ExpandProperty Node |
                          Select-Object -ExpandProperty Value
            $AccessMask = Select-Xml -Xml $xml -Namespace $ns -XPath "//e:Data[@Name='AccessMask']/text()" |
                          Select-Object -ExpandProperty Node |
                          Select-Object -ExpandProperty Value
            $out.AppendLine("$($svr),$($evt.id),$($evt.TimeCreated),$SubjectUserName,$ObjectName,$AccessMask")
            Write-Host $svr
            Write-Host $evt.id, $evt.TimeCreated, $SubjectUserName, $ObjectName,$AccessMask
        }
    }
}
$out.ToString() | Out-File -FilePath "C:\Temp\X4663Events.csv"
```

I have no idea, why no file is processed. The file will be created, but it is empty execpt for the headline.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-6

Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Test\*.txt -Recurse -Force

This example displays .txt files that are located in the current directory and its subdirectories

Comment: Did you verify that `Get-ChildItem "C:\temp\raw_data" -Recurse` really doesn't list the files you're expecting? Are you getting errors when running that statement alone?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers get-Childitem "c:\temp\raw_data" -recurse shows all the relevant files. But still no result is given to the export-file. its empty

Comment: @YasushiHiroNakamura - so ... is there anything in `$evts` when the 1st file is processed? if so, is there anything in the 1st `$evt` in the `foreach` that follows it? ///// this is standard diagnostics [*grin*] ... have you found out where the failure point is?

Comment: @Lee_Dailey i'm not able to get an result when  using write-host $evt or write-host $evts. it doesn't matters in which line i add this in the code somewher below $evts = Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{Path=$_;id="4663"} -Oldest

Comment: @YasushiHiroNakamura - that seems to mean that this >>> `Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{Path=$_;id="4663"}` <<< is not working. can you get it to work if you do that line manually with one of the files in question?

Comment: @Lee_Dailey i changed the line $evts to get-winevent -path "c:\temp\raw_data\filename.evtx -filterhashtable @{id=4663} , still not success. i played with powershell the hole day now, so i give it up right now.

Comment: Remove the scriptblock around the `$evts = ...; foreach (...) {...}` and try again. Why is there a nested scriptblock in the first place?

Comment: Yes, there's an extra pair of curly braces { } inside the foreach-object { }.  Also $xml needs to be cast to [xml], so it's not just a string.  `[xml]$xml = $evt.ToXml()`.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't have to be that hard.  Typical powershell looks more like this.  Build an object, then export to csv.  Know what you're doing, and verify each piece.

```
$evts = get-winevent security -MaxEvents 3

$objs = foreach ($evt in $evts) {
  [xml]$xml = $evt.toxml()

  $subjectusername = $xml.event.EventData.data |
    where name -eq subjectusername |
    select -expand '#text'
  $subjectdomainname = $xml.event.EventData.data |
    where name -eq subjectdomainname |
    select -expand '#text'

  [pscustomobject]@{
    SubjectUserName = $subjectusername
    SubjectDomainName = $subjectdomainname
  }

}

$objs
$objs | export-csv mylog.csv
get-content mylog.csv


SubjectUserName SubjectDomainName
--------------- -----------------
SYSTEM          NT AUTHORITY
MYCOMP$         AD
MYCOMP$         AD


#TYPE System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject
"SubjectUserName","SubjectDomainName"
"SYSTEM","NT AUTHORITY"
"MYCOMP$","AD"
"MYCOMP$","AD"
```